# Android development database overuse solution

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I just started using a database in my android development journey,along with the MVVM arhitectural pattern,and the way I'm using it,even though i followed a tutorial for this,seems like a very expensive way to use a database.I'm saying this based purely on intuition because i know nothing about efficency and the cost of the operations.

Basically I have a recycler view and i use a query to load the items in the recycler view adapter.But,and this is very important,the query function returns a Live Data list,and whenever the data changes,the query gets called again because im observing the data with an observer(I don't know exactly if the query gets called every time,but that's what i think is happening,I'll let you decide).Is this method good or is it too expensive(talking about big projects here)

Here is my function for loading the data:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM basket_items")
fun loadBasketItems(): LiveData<List<BasketItem>> --> This is in my @Dao


fun loadBasketItems() = db.getBasketDao().loadBasketItems() --> This is in my repository

fun loadBasketItems() = repository.loadBasketItems() --> This is in my view model
```

And this is in my fragment,where the recycler view data updates when i make a change,like delete an item for example(I have a delete button for every item,and i delete them straight from the data base with a query function from my @Dao).Also i should use DiffUtil instead of changing the adapter every time something in the data changes,but that's beside the point(I think :d)

```
 viewModel.loadBasketItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            adapter = BasketFragmentAdapter(it, viewModel, requireContext())
            recycler.adapter = adapter
        })
```

Comment: creating and setting a new adapter every time your live data changes is pretty questionable. adapters don't change, the data inside them do. find a better way of changing the data inside your adapter, then notify it that data has changed. `adapter = BasketFragmentAdapter(it, viewModel, requireContext())` is redundant, you really only need something like `adapter.items = it` and then notifyDatasetChanged, although there are even better solutions

Comment: The depth of those database operations is not something that You should worry about when it comes to expensive computations especially because You are creating a new `Adapter` for the `RecyclerView` which is for sure computationally expensive as @a_local_nobody pointed out. You should think about refactoring this part in the first place if You feel like optimizing Your code.

Comment: Yea,i know,i learned that by now just didn't get the chance to change it,but what about my main question,doesn't the query get executed every time the data changes?

Comment: realistically, i don't think the amount of data you're loading will cause a problem, but there is a thing as loading too much data at a time. if you load 100 records here, chances are your recycler is really only showing X amount of those at a time, so you can consider using paging, if you're really worried about performance, although i doubt this would matter

Comment: Ok,but is it okey to let the query get called for every small change i make.Let's say i change something at an item,then the whole database table is loaded again just for one small change

Comment: most likely, it'll be fine. live data is an observer which will alert you of data changes, but it's only one option available to you. if you think it's loading and processing too much data, you can always NOT use it and try to find a more efficient way of doing it yourself, but usually you'll realize this will require just as much work and processing. loading 10-20-100 and even maybe 1000 items at a time will probably make almost no impact in your app